# Where can I find the jdatepicker jar file?

Tags: java, swing

Where can I find the jdatepicker jar file? Is there an
 alternative to jdatepicker in swing?

Comment: [Here, to be precise](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjdatepicker132jar.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the jar from maven central repo. [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdatepicker/jdatepicker/1.3.4)

you can use `DatePicker` as an alternative. see [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm)